# Bitrix component and module customisation

Tags: customization, bitrix

I am working with Bitrix24. I want to customise the component and module of Bitrix24.
But I didn't have the standard documentation for this.
Some one help me for the same,how we can work with local folder for customise component and module etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change logic of component you may do through this way:

1. create the `local` folder in your `documet_root` path
2. create `components` folder in the `local` folder
3. create `bitrix` folder in the `components` folder
4. copy component folder from `/bitrix/components/bitrix` to
   `/local/components/bitrix`
5. edit logic in the `component.php` file (or in `class.php` file if
   component using new bitrix core - D7) in the copied folder

If you need to change only the view, this is another way:

1. Instead of creating the `/local/components/bitrix` you have to
   create `/local/templates/.default/` folder
2. Copy there only the `.default` template of a needed component
3. Edit `template.php` file

With the second way, you also may change (or rich it) some data in final `$arResult` array provided for the template.php, just create `result_modifier.php` file in the template directory.

You can find this and other information in the free course [Bitrix Framework](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68), pay attention to this link, it will be very helpful

Comment: What is bitrix core - D7?

Comment: This is the new bitrix core for the product version  above than 14.0, with own ORM and other features, more info [here](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68&CHAPTER_ID=05959&LESSON_PATH=5936.5959)

Comment: thanks for help...One last help what is result_modifier and how we can create and where result_modifier.php

Comment: This is a helper file in a template folder, it works between the controller (component.php) and view (template.php) and it helps to change some data in result array before they are been sent to the template. This [scheme](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68&LESSON_ID=6087) may be helpful